# Weblogic and Hibernate 3.6.5, migrating DB layer from Oracle 10g to 11g, pitfalls, gotachas and experiences?

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, weblogic, oracle11gr2

We currently have a large enterprise java-based codebase consisting of numerous legacy and new projects running within Weblogic using frameworks such as struts 1, spring MVC, etc.

We use hibernate 3.6.5 as our ORM.

Our IT is upgrading the database layer from Oracle 10g to 11g. They are looking after all db and pl/sql related issue relating to that.

From the code/java/weblogic/hibernate point of view, is there anything we should be specially aware of? Hibernate 3.6.5 supports Oracle 11g and the same dialect is used, so technically speaking there should be no difference whatsoever from client side.

Am I missing something? If you had experience with a similar migration could you please share any gotchas and pitfalls you may have stumbled upon so that we can look for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to specifically set the Oracle dialect to 10g, because Hibernate 3.6.x does not autodetect Oracle 11g. If your application fully relies on the SQL statements generated by Hibernate, you should be fine.

If you use some explicit Oracle SQL statements, you might need to doublechek if they still work - 11gR2 tightened up SQL syntax checks comparing to 10g. Also, if you have explicit SQL and have some hints in it, you might as well delete hints and do perfromance testing all over again - chances are you will need different hints in different places than before. Good luck!